# Postman gRPC get response value

Tags: postman, grpc

I'm wondering if you could help with this one. After invoking grpc request I would like to get a value from response message and I can't figure it out how it works. Let's say I get this response:

```
{
    "status": "SUCCESS",
    "psp_reference": "1234",   
}
```

I would like to access psp_reference value and store it to a variable.

I've tried doing this

```
var jsonData = pm.response.messages.get("psp_reference")
pm.environment.set("id", jsonData)
```

Unfortunately, I am getting null value. Obviously, I would like to get 1234 value

Thanks for help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the gRPC response messages from postman using `pm.response.messages.all()`.

Assuming you are receiving a single message, here is an example that will log and then set the value in a postman environment variable:

```js
console.log(pm.response.messages.all()[0].data.psp_reference)
pm.environment.set("myEnvVariable", pm.response.messages.all()[0].data.psp_reference);
```

Comment: Thank you, that works absolutely perfect